How much DCEU canon carries over into the DCU?
I recently watched the first two episodes of Creature Commandos (2024), the first entry in the DC Universe (DCU), which is a reboot of the DC Extended Universe (DCEU). Interestingly, Creature Commandos, created and written by James Gunn, directly references events from his DCEU projects, The Suicide Squad (2021) and the TV series Peacemaker (2022). For instance, Creature Commandos mentions Project Starfish and Rick Flag Jr.'s death from The Suicide Squad, as well as Leota Adebayo (Amanda Waller's daughter) exposing Project Butterfly and Task Force X (the Suicide Squad) along with Waller's involvement to the public in Peacemaker.
Both The Suicide Squad and Peacemaker include references to major DC characters that haven't been introduced in the DCU yet. For example, The Suicide Squad mentions Robert DuBois / Bloodsport being imprisoned for shooting Superman with a Kryptonite bullet. Superman, Wonder Woman, Aquaman, and The Flash not only appear in Peacemaker but are also referenced (along with Batman and Green Arrow) as if they’re established figures within that universe, with Peacemaker even poking fun at them in Season 1.
Am I supposed to understand that Bloodsport shot the DCU's Superman (to be played by David Corenswet) with a Kryptonite bullet? And was Peacemaker making fun of the DCU's Justice League, implying they’re already established superheroes in Peacemaker Season 1?
Given these overlaps between supposedly separate universes and the fact that there's going to be a second season of Peacemaker set in the DCU, how much of the DCEU is actually considered canon within the new DCU continuity?

My understanding is that the Suicide Squad movies and Peacemaker are canon in the new DCU but the cameos of the JL at the end of Peacemaker S1 are not and will be retconned away. The characters will still exist but the actors will not.

While nothing before the DCU's first entry, Creature Commandos, will be considered canon in the new universe, Gunn has revealed that any events from the DCEU that are mentioned in DCU projects will become canon. Gunn has further stated that most of Peacemaker Season 1, except the Justice League cameo scene, is canon in the DCU, even though the 8-episode season itself isn't

Well, Peacemaker S2 is gonna be in DCU, so the titular character's story should be pretty much intact, but the Justice League stuff no, seeing how there's gonna be new Supes. More than that, time will tell.
